# Was the Inclusion of Generics in Java 5.0 Worthwhile?

Tags: java, generics

Aside from the added complexity, do you think that the inclusion of the Generics Mechanism in Java 5.0 was worthwhile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Couldn't live without it!  Do you *want* to go back to casting-from-Object in every container access and dealing with the resulting runtime-revealed type errors?!  Basically destroys *any* rationale for using an *allegedly* statically typed language (and if I use a dynamically typed language, it's going to be Python or Javascript, not Java;-).  Generics are a must for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Each and every cast in a Java program is a ClassCastException waiting to happen.  Hence, using generics to avoid casting in the first place, means you have less opportunity for failure.

Perhaps you need to have programmed in a language with strong typing to appreciate that.  I can recommend Haskell for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generics is usefull to check types in compilation time